# WordPress, PolyLang и главная страница

Tags: wordpress, интернационализация, polylang

Есть небольшой корпоративный сайт на WordPress'e v5.3, его настроил один человек несколько месяцев назад и ушёл. Всё работало хорошо, но понадобилось добавить языковую поддержку. Мой выбор пал на плагин PolyLang в виду его популярности. Вроде бы процесс перевода пошёл неплохо, менюшку с выбором языка прикрутил, но появилась следующая проблема.

Если зайти на сайт по пустому URI `/` с чистым браузером, то отображается нужная страница "Home", она же висит по адресу `/?page_id=12`. Страница оформлена через шаблон, заполнена нужным контентом и должна быть лендингом.

Однако, после выбора языка главная страница превращается в страницу последних записей, адрес становится `/?lang=ru`. Последующая смена на `/` возвращает туда же. Видимо, язык сохраняется в куки, а главная страница указывает на `/?page_id=12` только в случае отсутствия прочих параметров.

Как исправить это поведение, сделать отображение корректной страницы по нужному адресу с выбранным языком?

Comment: в настройках полиленга настройте правильно слаги.

Comment: @Krya К сожалению, в настройке аддона кроме платной опции `Share slugs` про слаги ничего нет 